# How to ensure that webhook is receiving data from desired data source and not third party?

Tags: node.js, rest, http, security, webhooks

I'm currently building out an application that utilizes Shippo's webhooks functionality, but wondering if it's possible to ensure that the HTTP POST requests are coming from Shippo's servers rather than some malicious third party.

Adding a webhook to Shippo:
https://shippo-static.s3.amazonaws.com/img/illustrations/webhooks.png

When recieving HTTP requests, it appears as though Shippo doesn't provide a key or anything that I can use on my end to verify that the request came from shippo themselves. Is there any way that I would be able to retroactively and securely ensure that the request came from Shippo's servers?

Sample headers:

> User-Agent: python-requests/2.9.1
>
> Via: 1.1 vegur
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Connection: close
>
> Content-Length: 2203
>
> Total-Route-Time: 0
>
> Cf-Connecting-Ip: 54.87.248.176
>
> Cf-Ipcountry: US
>
> X-Request-Id: cec0a1aa-6a1a-47e9-ac9d-c685a893591d
>
> Cf-Ray: 3d0718455e149fea-IAD
>
> Connect-Time: 1
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip
>
> Host: requestb.in
>
> Shippo-Api-Version: 2017-08-01
>
> Cf-Visitor: {"scheme":"https"}
>
> Content-Type: application/json

Sample JSON Response:
https://goshippo.com/docs/tracking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Have your webhook include some sort of token, i.e. have shippo call `https://yourapp.com/webhookroute/?secure_token=123abc`. Parse and check the token server side. Can add multiple tokens, i.e. `https://yourapp.com/webhookroute/?secure_token_1=123abc&secure_token_2=456def`
2. Use SSL/TLS certs when deploying your app, which will encrypt the URL/tokens when shippo sends the webhook. Make sure the webhook calls https:// [rest of url], not http://. This will hide the tokens from the rest of the internet.

If the tokens are set as env vars server side, this should be secure.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a ton!

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Great thank you.